# why is my string replace not working in c++?

Tags: c++

I wrote this loop to replace all quotes in a string:

```
void remQuotes(string& s) {
    while (int x = s.find("\"") != string::npos) {
        s = s.replace(x,1,"");
    }
}
```

unfortunately it created an infinite loop as soon as an argument had a quote in it.  I don't understand why this is not working.

Comment: Because of operator precedence.

Comment: this works on my machine actually (kind of); asd"f becomes af

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is likely not doing what you expect. Let's add the appropriate parentheses to show how your code is being parsed:

```
while (int x = (s.find("\"") != string::npos)) {
```

Let's fix it by adding the correct parentheses:

```
void remQuotes(string& s) {
    while ((int x = s.find("\"")) != string::npos) {
        s = s.replace(x,1,"");
    }
}
```

But this would be clearer as:

```
void remQuotes(string& s) {
    while (true) {
        int x = s.find("\"");
        if (x == string::npos)
            return;
        s = s.replace(x, 1, "");
    }
}
```

But you should really just do:

```
void remQuotes(string& s) {
    auto it = std::remove(s.begin(), s.end(), '\"');
    s.erase(it, s.end());
}
```

Comment: this does not actually answer my question

Comment: Operator precedence. Your code does: `while (int x = (s.find("\"") != string::npos)) {`, which is likely now what you intended.

Comment: why can't I just put parentheses around (int x=s.find("\""))?

Comment: @msknapp: That's exactly what I have in the answer.

Comment: @msknapp `!=` has a higher precedence than `=` so the comparison is evaluated first and the result is assigned to `x`. Since the comparison always evaluates to true `x` is always true. This causes the infinite loop.